# Refresh iframe when looking away (from within iframe itself)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page that embeds an iframe with a Unity game in it, the game isn't loaded until the user actually clicks in the iframe. This to make sure the page loads quickly, and no games are running that aren't being played (there can be multiple games on one page).

Now I was wondering, is it possible to make the iframe refresh when the user scrolls away? So the game stops running and the again waits for a click. Is it possible by only changing the page being shown by the iframe? (So not the page that has the iframe.)

Note: I have limited control over the actual page embedding the iframe, that's why it would be nice if this could be done by the page being shown by the iframe.

Edit: I found this for refreshing: `self.location.reload();`, now I only need to be able to detect if the iframe is in view from within the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detect if the iframe is in the viewport of an external site, because you cannot access the document of the parent domain from within the iframe. That would be needed to determine the position of the iframe element on the page.

Comment: Ah shame :( I found that it wasn't possible for elements in the iframe, but couldn't find anything about the iframe itself.

Comment: Yeah it would be useful for saving resources for something like a unity game, but also an attack vector.

Comment: True, so probably best that they leave it so. I'll have to see what I can do on the parent page itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe src is within the same domain as the parent window then it would be possible. In your game page, you could detect a scroll event in the parent window like this:

```
var parent = window.parent;
parent.onscroll = function (e) {  
   // the parent window has scrolled,
   // you can pause the game here
}
```

Then you can detect a the user clicking on the iframe by just adding a click event.

```
window.onclick = function() {
   // user has clicked on the iframe,
   // you can initialise the game now
}
```

Comment: "Note: I have limited control over the actual page embedding the iframe, that's why it would be nice if this could be done by the page being shown by the iframe."

Comment: Yes, the click I can detect. But as Tui correctly assumed, I meant to imply that the domains are indeed different.

Comment: Ah ok, I assumed that 'limited' may suggest you had some accessibility